# How to plot multiples of a fixed subplot2grid arrangement each consisting of several plots into one figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Imagine the following as one subplot in a figure of shape (n,1):

```
ax0 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=1)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (1,0), sharex=ax1, rowspan=4)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), sharex=ax1, rowspan=1)
```

(The subplot2grid arrangement may be more complex than this.)

I would like to plot n number of these in one figure.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That [is documented](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html#gridspec-using-subplotspec).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

gs0 = fig.add_gridspec(len(df_list), 1)

for i,v in enumerate(df_list):
    gs00 = gs0[i].subgridspec(6, 1)
    ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs00[0, 0])    
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs00[1:5, 0])
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs00[5, 0])
```